# How do I utilise Assembly from within WebAPI Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2017

I have a VS2017 WebAPI solution that I am working on at the moment. I need to make a call to an assembly (included in the solution) from within the Controller.  Much to my frustration it appears that I cannot make a call to methods within the assembly.

The graphic below I believe should supply sufficient detail for the right advice.  Likely I am trying to do something with the WebAPI project that it will not allow (but I hope not) :-)

[image]

### Update

On reflection the graphic doesn't appear to be all that legible. Within the PIInterfaceController I have added the following code:

```
 Imports System.Net.Http
 Imports System.Web.Http
 Imports SPEN.PIInterface

Namespace Controllers
Public Class PIInterfaceController
    Inherits ApiController

    Dim piServerSetting As String

    'Instantiate the SPEN PI Interface object so we can supply necessary data elements as required to extract the correct data from PI
    Dim piIntfc As New SPEN.PIInterface(piServerSetting)
    piIntfc.
End Class
End Namespace
```

My problem is that I am unable to access any of the methods from the PIInterface instance 'piIntfc'.

Comment: I'm not a vb.net expert but don't you need to be calling methods of piIntfc within a method of your controller ? If i try the same as what you're doing in a c# project i get the same problem.

Comment: Hmmm...  That is just so obvious, why couldnt i see that...  Thanks for the answer auburg.